# CSS: white-space: nowrap does not seems to work in IE

Tags: html, css

Here is the `jsfiddle` of the below code. http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/. What I want is the name `Harry Pham` to be in one line, so I make the width very small and do `white-space:nowrap`. It work on Firefox, but not IE. Help please

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 450px;">
   <tr>           
       <td>
           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                  <td style="width:20px;border-top:1px solid gray;white-space: nowrap;"><span class="linkColor">Harry Pham</span>
                  </td>
                  <td style="height:15px;background:url('images/line.png') no-repeat;width:28px;" width="35px"></td>
                  <td style="border-bottom:1px solid gray;" width="auto"></td>
              </tr>
           </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is very much the hard/awkward way. Forget CSS and margins and <span altogether. Just write Harry&nbsp;Pham. This is the recommended way to do things like this. (The "nbsp" entity name stands for Non-Breaking SPace.)

Comment: The question has been changed so that the **problem** is not presented in the question itself. Apparently the problem was that using `white-space: nowrap` on a `td` element did not work.

Comment: I have been struggling with IE10 recently and it seems to need the css rule `word-wrap: normal` to avoid wraping

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For IE 6 and 7 you need to wrap your text with a `<span>` tag and give it a `white-space` property. Since you already have a `<span>` tag wrapped around your text and you have a class for it, just add the `white-space` property to your `<span>` class `.linkColor`.

```
.linkColor{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/1/

Comment: I gave credit to the previous answer u gave me. Sorry, I forgot. I will test this answer out tomorrow, I am using MAC book, need to test this on PC at work which have IE. Thank you btw

Comment: If you dont mind, may I ask what is the `gold star` and `4M` next to your name mean?

Comment: oh I see, it is your avatar. hehe

Comment: This solution is great - thanks @Hussein!  In case it helps anyone:  It didn't work for me until I used a div instead of a span inside my td cell.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  Even with the answer, it took me a little time to get it to work.  So in case it helps anyone else, here is another jsfiddle that illustrates how to get "white-space: nowrap" to work with internet-explorer:  http://jsfiddle.net/zv8Yt/2/

Comment: Excellent. I've been looking for this fix for so long. Damn you IE!!

Comment: You need to add `display: inline-block` as well for this to work in IE8. This would be why it worked for you with a div instead of a span, because that's already block-level. I suspect IE will ignore whitespace settings on inline elements. No idea about IE6 or 7 but you're probably just out of luck there.

Comment: @pospi Yep. I had to change only `display: block` into `display: inline-block` in my CSS to make `whitespace: nowrap` working on `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
 for(var j=0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
 var button = buttons[j];
 var textNode = button;
 while(textNode.children[0]) {
 textNode = textNode.children[0];
 }
 var text, words, numSplits;
 var spacing = 0;
        while(button.scrollWidth !== 0 && button.clientWidth !== 0 &&
              button.scrollWidth > button.clientWidth) {
    if(!spacing) {
        text = textNode.innerHTML;
        words = text.split(' ');
        numSplits = Math.ceil(button.scrollWidth / button.clientWidth);
        spacing = Math.round((words.length)/numSplits);
    }
    for(var i = spacing; i < words.length; i+=spacing+1) {
        words.splice(i , 0, '<br />');
    }          
    textNode.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
    spacing--;
    words = text.split(' ');
}
}
```

Ref: [Word wrapping for button with specified width in ie7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808137/word-wrapping-for-button-with-specified-width-in-ie7?answertab=active#tab-top)