# Button wrap in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The value property is sometimes changed to be really long, longer than 50px.

```
<input type="submit" Value="Really long" style="width:50px; white-space:normal" />
```

This works fine in IE8+ and firefox in that the text on the button wraps to the next line.

The problem is this has to work in IE7 and the text does not wrap.

Does anyone know how to make it wrap in IE7?

Comment: In IE7 you have to include a manual line break in your HTML source. See answer below.

Comment: Here is the solution, it works fine for me :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808137/word-wrapping-for-button-with-specified-width-in-ie7?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 4):

I'm unfortunately still supporting IE7 and came across this issue. If you're able to change `<input />` to `<button>` you can nest a `<span>` inside of the button with `display:inline-block` to resolve the overflow issue.

```
<button>
    <span style="display:inline-block">Long button text goes here</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a kludge, but this will render mostly correct in IE7:

```
 <input type="submit" Value="Really 
 long" style="width:50px; white-space:normal" />
```

You basically have to add a line break in your HTML. This 'technique' is a work around... If you manually write your HTML it will be an option, but if your code is generated (e.g. ASP.Net), it may not work.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNcLD/) in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you wish to achieve, however, you may want to try using the size attribute in the input tag, AS WELL as your css.

`<input size="50" type="submit" Value="Really long" style="width:50px; white-space:normal" />`

Comment: The `size` attr. will be overwritten by the `width` CSS property.

Comment: Still, it is worth a shot, just in case (it wouldn't hurt)

Answer (score -1):

Insert a `<br />` into the value and make sure the `doctype` is correctly specified.

Comment: You cannot insert tags like <br> into values of attributes.