# Text not wrapping in button in IE7 browser

Tags: asp.net, styles

I have a button 
    . 
I want to wrap the text in the button its working fine for every browser, including IE 8 and IE 9. But not working for IE7. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle that uses a button with `width: 100px` that I've found in another question:
http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrytorba/dZyzr/247/

From question:
[Word wrapping for button with specified width in ie7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808137/word-wrapping-for-button-with-specified-width-in-ie7)