# CSS white-space nowrap IE fails but works Firefox/Chrome

Tags: css

I can't quite figure out what's wrong. In firefox/chrome I can successfully use nowrap and overflow-x but not in IE. Here's the relevant code block to disable wrapping...

```
#code_block {
  background: #A9A9A9;
  padding: 3px 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-family: "Courier New", "Lucida Console";
}
```

Source page: http://www.blissend.com/node/18
Source relevant css: block.css

Does anyone know why this doesn't work in IE10? Are there some requirements in IE for white-space: nowrap and overflow-x that could prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280521/css-white-space-nowrap-does-not-seems-to-work-in-ie

Comment: Code to reproduce the issue is not presented in the question. HTML code is missing.

Comment: Forgive me, I was lazy breaking down the massive amount of html/css and thought to see if anyone might know of possible IE10 quirks. The solution wasn't in the possible duplicate as it dealt with `word-wrap` interfering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with an inherited `word-wrap` value:

[image]

Try adding `word-wrap: keep-all` to `#code-block`.

Comment: That did the trick! Had to use `word-wrap: normal` since it doesn't look like `keep-all` is an option.